# JavaFX TreeItems not aligned correctly

Tags: java, treeview, alignment, javafx

I got a TreeView.
To every Item in this `TreeView` I add a bunch of other TreeItems dynamically if this `TreeItem` becomes expanded. (via a `ChangeListener` on `expandedProperty`)

But after expanding some TreeItems automatically through code, they wont get aligned properly, and I get something like this:

[image]

After scrolling up and down a little bit, I noticed, that sometimes It's aligned right and sometimes it's even worse.

Does anyone know a workaround? or is it a bug?

EDIT:

This should reproduce the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class TreeViewTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stg) throws Exception { 
    final TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<String>();

    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<String>("Root");

    genChilds(root, 50);

    tree.setRoot(root);

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(tree);

    TreeItem<String> leaf = root;
    for(int j = 0; j < leaf.getChildren().size() && leaf.getChildren().size() != 0; j++){
        System.out.println("b");
        if(Math.random() < 0.5){
        leaf = leaf.getChildren().get(j);
        leaf.setExpanded(true);
        tree.getSelectionModel().select(leaf);
        }
    }

    stg.setScene(new Scene(pane));
    stg.show(); 
    }

    protected int depth(TreeItem<String> selectedItem) {
    return 0;
    }

    private void genChilds(final TreeItem<String> leaf, final int count) {
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        final int nr = i;
        leaf.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>("" + i));
        leaf.getChildren().get(i).expandedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean newV) {
            if(newV){
            leaf.getChildren().get(nr).getChildren().remove(0);
            genChilds(leaf.getChildren().get(nr), count-1);
            }else{
            leaf.getChildren().get(nr).getChildren().clear();
            leaf.getChildren().get(nr).getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(""));
            }
        }
        });

        //End at some Point
        if(count-1 > 0)
        leaf.getChildren().get(i).getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(""));
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using? Can you post a simple example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Currently I'm using JFX 2.2.

Comment: Strange enough: I am currently facing the issue and cannot reproduce it with sample code. The code you provided does not reproduce the issue for me either. Did you find a fix for this by now?

Comment: I`m afraid but as far as I can remember I couldnt fix it. But if I remeber correctly, the behavior wasnt the same across different machines and different java versions (if I remeber correctly especially on WinXP the problem apperared). At that time java8 was in beta stage (not sure on that though) and i think we chose to go with the beta and it seemed to work then. But I´m not 100% certain. As it was a minor feature in my application it wasnt all that important.

Answer (score 0):

This code is perfectly working fine as it should. I tested it on Javafx 2.2. I think you should probably check inside your code.  I am using quite complex treeview in our application since a year, we never found any indentation problem.

Comment: The code I posted as well as the code inside my application produces, the weired results I described. No matter if I'm using javafx 2.2 or javafx 8. Really strange thing ...